Understanding the Image Measure and Joint Density Function Dependent on Realizations of X and Y
I'm currently working through a problem involving the integral of a loss function over a probability space, specifically:
$\int_{\Omega} \ell(f(X(\omega)), Y(\omega)) \, d\mathbb{P}(\omega).$
In this context, $X(\omega)$ and $Y(\omega)$ are random variables defined on the probability space $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, and $\ell$ is a given loss function.
I am looking for a deeper understanding of how the image measure and joint density function come into play, and how to construct a dominating measure such that the density exists.
How to determine the image measure induced by the random variables $X$ and $Y$?
is this the implicit assumption here that the realizations of X and Y are jointly distributed according to the image measure?
